# CentOS 8.5.2111 with EPEL repository: Upgrading Ansible via dnf fails

Tags: centos, ansible, dnf

I've installed ansible-2.9.27-1.el8.noarch on a CentOS Linux release 8.5.2111 machine. For this I've enabled the "epel-release" repo using "dnf install epel-release".

When I try to upgrade Ansible using "dnf upgrade ansible" I get a weird "nothing provides (ansible-core >= 2.12.2 with ansible-core < 2.13) needed by ansible-5.4.0-2.el8.noarch" error:

[image]

```
[root@jenkins-master ~]# rpm -qR ansible
/usr/bin/python3.6
config(ansible) = 2.9.27-1.el8
python(abi) = 3.6
python3-jinja2
python3-jmespath
python3-pyyaml
python3-setuptools
python3-six
python3.6dist(cryptography)
python3.6dist(jinja2)
python3.6dist(pyyaml)
rpmlib(CompressedFileNames) <= 3.0.4-1
rpmlib(FileDigests) <= 4.6.0-1
rpmlib(PartialHardlinkSets) <= 4.0.4-1
rpmlib(PayloadFilesHavePrefix) <= 4.0-1
rpmlib(PayloadIsXz) <= 5.2-1
sshpass
```

```
[root@jenkins-master ~]# dnf provides *ansible-core*
Failed to set locale, defaulting to C.UTF-8
Last metadata expiration check: 1:20:35 ago on Tue Jun  7 13:37:36 2022.
ansible-5.4.0-2.el8.noarch : Curated set of Ansible collections included in addition to ansible-core
Repo        : epel
Matched from:
Other       : *ansible-core*
```

```
[root@jenkins-slave1 yum.repos.d]# ls -1
CentOS-Linux-AppStream.repo
CentOS-Linux-BaseOS.repo
CentOS-Linux-ContinuousRelease.repo
CentOS-Linux-Debuginfo.repo
CentOS-Linux-Devel.repo
CentOS-Linux-Extras.repo
CentOS-Linux-FastTrack.repo
CentOS-Linux-HighAvailability.repo
CentOS-Linux-Media.repo
CentOS-Linux-Plus.repo
CentOS-Linux-PowerTools.repo
CentOS-Linux-Sources.repo
docker.repo
epel-modular.repo
epel-testing-modular.repo
epel-testing.repo
epel.repo

[root@jenkins-slave1 yum.repos.d]# grep enabled=1 *
CentOS-Linux-AppStream.repo:enabled=1
CentOS-Linux-BaseOS.repo:enabled=1
CentOS-Linux-Extras.repo:enabled=1
epel-modular.repo:enabled=1
epel.repo:enabled=1
epel.repo:enabled=1
epel.repo:enabled=1
```

Does anyone know how to resolve this ? Is it related to the CentOS stream switch ?

Comment: What does `rpm -qR ansible`  tell you?

Comment: can you run `dnf provides *ansible-core*`  and see what it returns?

Comment: The `ansible-core` package seems to be provided by `appstream` repository. Here is how the repository looks like:  https://dpaste.org/gSJps     . So within `/etc/yum.repos.d/CentOS-Stream-AppStream.repo` file (create this file) paste the content from the link and run `dnf update && dnf install ansible-core`

Comment: Hm, but this machine is running CentOS 8.5 and not CentOS Stream ... is it still ok to add that repo ?

Comment: It should work perfectly fine. For the long term you need to migrate to CentOS stream or, RockyLinux(preferably)  and or AlmaLinux.

Comment: hm, unfortunately the AppStream repository was already present and enabled. Disabling the EPEL repository didn't help either ... maybe I need to completely deinstall and re-install Ansible with only the AppStream repo enabled ...

Comment: Yes, you don't need to disable it permanently but you can do it temporarily using `dnf install ansible --disablerepo epel`

Comment: I now permanently disabled the EPEL repo and afterwards "dnf upgrade" turns up no errors anymore. Thanks a lot for your help !

Comment: Keine dank Tobias. VIel spas